# Update status will show user name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Previously in my app only the owner of a guideline could edit his own guideline, but I would like anyone to be able to edit a guideline and then when it has updated it will say 'Edited by .... on .... date'.  Is this possible?

my update action in guidelines_controller.rb is

```
def update
    @guideline = Guideline.find(params[:id])

    if params[:guideline] && params[:guideline].has_key?(:user_id)
        params[:guideline].delete(:user_id) 
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @guideline.update_attributes(params[:guideline])
        format.html { redirect_to @guideline, notice: 'Guideline was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "show" }
        format.json { render json: @guideline.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

and edit action in the same controller is

```
 def edit

      @guideline = Guideline.find(params[:id])
      @specialties = Guideline.order(:specialty).uniq.pluck(:specialty)

  end
```

User Model user.rb is

```
 attr_accessible :content, :hospital, :title, :user_id, :guideline_id, :specialty
 has_many :guidelines
 has_many :favourite_guidelines
```

guidelines model is

```
belongs_to :user
 has_many :favourite_guidelines
```

Comment: can you show the associations for user and guideline.

Comment: Is there any column in guidelines table that keeps track of user who has last edited it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the history of the edits, then you have to create another table (guideline_edits : guideline_id, user_id, edited_at) and you can show the last edited by  at . If you also want to track the changes that went into each of the edits, you can actually use [audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited) gem

If you do not want to maintain the history, you can add edited_by (current user), edited_at (Time.now()) fields to your guideline and update these columns on updating the guideline.

And ofcourse, in your authorization rules, you have to allow any logged-in user to edit any guideline.

Hope this helps